# SolidBrush.Clone throws exception

Tags: c#, winforms, clone, brush, solidcolorbrush

I'm using different types of brushes like **`SolidBrush`**, **`HatchBrush`**, etc.., to draw complex shapes and text in my windows forms control. The code I'm using is,

```
protected void FillShape(Brush myBrush, GraphicsPath shape)
        {
            if (myBrush is SolidBrush)
            {
                using (SolidBrush sbr = myBrush.Clone() as SolidBrush)
                {
                    //Code for drawing with solid brush
                }
            }
            else if (myBrush is HatchBrush)
            {                    
                    //Code for drawing with hatch brush
            }
            else if (myBrush is LinearGradientBrush)
            {
                    //Code for drawing with linear gradient brush
            }
            else if (myBrush is PathGradientBrush)
            {
                    //Code for drawing with path gradient brush
            }
        }
```

Some times, the line `myBrush.Clone()` throws `ArgumentException`. I searched MSDN link for SolidBrush.Clone() method but there is no information about any exception
[SolidBrush.Clone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.solidbrush.clone%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

So, I checked the source code for this method in following link [Reference code for SolidBrush class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/SolidBrush.cs)

The code used in `System.Drawing.SolidBrush.Clone` method is

```
public override object Clone() 
        {
            IntPtr cloneBrush = IntPtr.Zero;

            int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipCloneBrush(new HandleRef(this, this.NativeBrush), out cloneBrush);

            if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
                throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);

            // We intentionally lose the "immutable" bit.

            return new SolidBrush(cloneBrush);
        }
```

It is clear, that the `Clone` method may throw exception but I'm not able to identify when or why it will throw exception, since this code is not mine.

Does anyone know when or why exception will be thrown by this method ?

Edit:

Attached the image showing exception details

[image: Exception Image]

Also, this is not a system brush, because `immutable` property of the brush is `false`

[image: Not a system brush]

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but since you write it throws only sometimes, maybe these are cases when you pass in a Standard Brush which can't be disposed as the using clause will try to do..

Comment: `ArgumentException` could be anything, especially when you don't provide the _exact_ message text and stack trace. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to write a good, answerable question.

Comment: The line `using (SolidBrush sbr = myBrush.Clone() as SolidBrush)` is pointless. There is no sense in creating a copy of a brush only to dispose it. Just use the original `myBrush` without disposing it (aka without the `using` statement).

Comment: @Loathing, I'm using clone because I'm making some changes to the solid brush like changing color etc. I have also tried your suggestion without cloning but it throws same exception when changing color, I'll give more details about this exception soon in my question, thanks

Comment: @All, added details about the exception and details about the brush object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could determine if it is actually the `Clone()` that is throwing the exception or the disposing. If you try to dispose or change a SystemBrush, then an exception will occur:

```
SystemBrushes.Control.Dispose(); // ArgumentException: Changes cannot be made to Brush because permissions are not valid.
```

But cloning it and then disposing it works fine:

```
((Brush) SystemBrushes.Control.Clone()).Dispose(); // OK
```

So maybe just avoid `Clone` altogether if you think that is the problem, e.g:

```
    // instead of using clone, just make a new instance
    Brush myBrush = SystemBrushes.Control;
    if (myBrush is SolidBrush) {
        using (var nb = new SolidBrush(((SolidBrush) myBrush).Color)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but the brush is not a system brush, edited the question for more details

Comment: @Anand That exception will occur when you are trying to `Clone` a brush that is already disposed.